# Detaching Console on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

My problem is that when I right click on the console, I don't see "Detach". It just shows "Close" .

I've seen places saying to right click on the console and click on "Detach" to detach the console.

I'm using Eclipse Junor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try dragging the console tab handle outside the Eclipse window.

Comment: thanks for the very simple method. Wonder why I didn't think of it before .... ;-)